# Problem with nvarchar data with XML in SQL server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

```
Create table testxml
(xmldata xml)

declare @var nvarchar(max)
set @var = N'الوفاق الوطني المخ'

insert into testxml
select @var
```

After inserting , i am getting data from table like

```
select * from testxml
---------------------
????????
```

Can you provide me the solution?

Comment: What is the collation of your database?

Comment: I've tested this and I get the Arabian characters, not the question marks

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an encoding problem with your terminal.
You may use these commands to have more information on your encoding properties.

sp_helpsort;

SERVERPROPERTY ( collation )

Answer (score 0):

this should help as GABS said :

SELECT SERVERPROPERTY ('collation' )

to see the list of collation and update(mine is Latin1_General_CI_AI)

SELECT * FROM ::fn_helpcollations()